# Preprocessor macro definition of a macro definition

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

The C++ standard has a way of converting the function a line is in into a char array, but it doesn't take account of class qualifications (doesn't include outer classes the function is nested in. However there are a bunch of compiler extensions that do, and do other things like include the function signature. I wanted to do something like this:

```
#ifdef VISUAL_STUDIO
#define _FUNCTION_NAME_ __FUNCTION__
#else 
#define _FUNCTION_NAME_ __func__
#endif
```

Roughly. Now, **FUNCTION** itself, or say **PRETTY_FUNCTION** on GCC or anything else, may be macros themselves. What happens when a macro itself follows a macro definition?

```
#define MY_FIRST_DEFINE 6 + 1
#define MY_SECOND_DEFINE MY_FIRST_DEFINE
```

In Visual Studio if I do the above and in main I do:

```
MY_SECOND_DEFINE; // Expands correctly, to 6 + 1
```

If I reverse the order of the two:

```
#define MY_SECOND_DEFINE MY_FIRST_DEFINE
#define MY_FIRST_DEFINE 6 + 1
```

It still expands correctly, to 6 + 1. I've even tried this with three levels (MY_THIRD_DEFINE), and it never matters which order they're in, it always works. So basically, can I rely on this working every time? Is it a standardised feature of the C++ preprocessor (or is it C?) that basically, as far as I can see, it does something like this:

1. While parsing the code/text check to see if any string matches one of the macro defines.
2. If it does, check to see if the definition for the macro is a macro definition itself.
3. Recursively do this until the macro definition isn't a macro definition itself.
4. If the definition isn't a macro definition itself then do the normal macro expansion

Thinking about 'defines of defines' isn't something I really want to think about and stay away from, but I kind of need to know if the **FUNCTION** macro thing is going to work. Also, I've tagged this C++ because that's the language I'm using, and I don't know if the preprocessor is the exact same one as the C language.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__` are not and cannot be macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I rely on this working every time?

Yes.

> Is it a standardised feature of the C++ preprocessor (or is it C?)

Both.

> it does something like this:

Generally, basically, let's say yes. Macros are expanded upon use. The result of expansion is "rescanned for more macro names to replace", let's say recursively with some [special rules](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4).

Identifiers starting with `_` and upper case letter are reserved. You can't use `_FUNCTION_NAME_` in your code. Use `FUNCTION_NAME`. See [gcc docs on reserved names](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html). You might be interested in how [glibc assert.h __ASSERT_FUNCTION](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/assert/assert.h#L125) did it.